# How to extract values from xml in body using xpath in camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I have an http response that is set in my exchange body. I have to extract some values from that xml. I found that the best way could be using camel-xpath. I have to extract value from root tag level. For example in the xml below, the value i want to extract would be attribute1.

```
<rootTag attribute1="value1">
<child1/>
</rootTag>
```

I saw some examples that use namespace. But i don't think i have the scope of using namespace here. If so, how could i do that. Could i not directly extract it from the body of the exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract your attribute to the message header:

```
.setHeader("MyHeader").xpath("/rootTag/@attribute1", String.class)
```

or put attribute to the body:

```
.setBody().xpath("/rootTag/@attribute1", String.class)
```

Your do not need namespaces here..

And @Gilles Quenot is certainly right about the xpath expression.

Comment: I have been trying to do the same thing with jsonpath. here using xpath we have extracted the data from the xml. could we do the same using jsonpath..or is there some other way by which i could get the value in the json and set it to header/body/property etc??

Comment: Yes @Susanna M, you could : `.setHeader("City").jsonpath("$.city", true)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the Xpath you need :

```
string(/rootTag/@attribute1)
```

## tests in a shell

### [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/rootTag/@attribute1' file
```

### [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) :

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'string(/rootTag/@attribute1)' file
```

### [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) :

```
$ xidel -se '/rootTag/@attribute1' file
```

### Output :

```
value1
```